Why i am getting 400 Bad Request when i include page parameter for GetJobLogs { GET /20180917/jobs/{jobId}/logs } from oci .net sdk?
i am trying to send a initial request to to get the details of the job logs and when i include the page parameter, the response gives bad request error and also i want to include pagination in my request to handle a very large list of job logs.
GET /20180917/jobs/{jobId}/logs
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/resourcemanager/20180917/Job/GetJobLogs
my intial job request looks like the one given below :-
var initialjobsrequest = new GetJobLogsRequest()
{
    JobId = jobId,
    Type = new List<JobLogEntry.TypeEnum>
    {
        JobLogEntry.TypeEnum.TerraformConsole
    },
    LevelGreaterThanOrEqualTo = JobLogEntry.LevelEnum.Info,
    SortOrder = GetJobLogsRequest.SortOrderEnum.Asc,
    Limit = 1000,
    Page = null
};


when I don't include the page parameter its gives me 200 ok response but when page parameter is  included then it gives 400 bad request.
What do i need to do to include the page parameter and how can i handle pagination in such scenario and also how to fetch the page token for next response?

What are you passing as the Page = parameter to get the bad request error? Are you using a value gained from the opc-next-page header of a previous request?
